Interpretation of the intercept coefficient in GLMMs
Suppose that I have a dataset with three variables; response, gender and area, where the response is binary. If I run a glm model;
 glm(reponse ~ gender, family = ‘binomial’)

The intercept is the mean response at the reference category and supposing that male is the reference category, if I filter male in the dataset and find the empirical mean, then it will match with the model’s intercept. However, if I run a mixed effect model;
 glmer(reponse ~ gender + 1|area, family = ‘binomial’)

The intercept does not match the empirical mean. Why does this happen?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is worthwhile examining each model.  The first model is
$$ \operatorname{logit}(p_i)  = \beta_0 + \beta_1\mbox{gender}_i$$
for binary gender.  The second model is
$$ \operatorname{logit}(p_i)  = \beta_0 + \beta_1\mbox{gender}_i + \beta_{0, area[i]}$$
$$ \beta_{0, area[i]} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0, \sigma^2) $$
In essence, the second model estimates a separate intercept per group defined by area.  It isn't exactly like this (because this particular structure induces a bit of regularization, but that is beyond the scope of this answer).
Roughly, we can say that $\beta_0$ is the log odds of the reference group, were I to repeatedly sample units defined by area, and estimate log odds of their outcome.

Thank you. β1gender still represents the change between the reference category and the category shown by the R output?

@B.MNjuguna Correct
